# Is there a way to "expand" a list of objects into a bigger list with stream API?

Tags: java, java-8

Consider this example: I have a list of RangeSet that contains, for instance, timestamps. I want to get the total duration of ranges using java8 streams instead of the imperative way:

```
// "list" is List<RangeSet<Long>>

long totalTime = list.stream()
    .expand(rangeset -> rangeset.asRanges())
    .map(range -> range.upperEndpoint() - range.lowerEndpoint())
    .reduce(0, (total, time) -> total + time);
```

The "expand" of course doesn't exist ; the idea is it would convert each single object in the stream to a list of other objects, and add that list to the resulting stream.

Is there something similar, or another way to do it fluently?

Comment: `list.stream().flatMap(rangeset -> rangeset.asRanges().stream()).mapToInt(range -> range.upperEndpoint() - range.lowerEndpoint()).sum()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking for [`Stream.flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), e.g.

```
long totalTime = list.stream()
    .flatMap(rangeset -> rangeset.asRanges().stream())
    .map(range -> range.upperEndpoint() - range.lowerEndpoint())
    .reduce(0, (total, time) -> total + time);
```