# Can a Java 8 stream process an expanding number of elements?

Tags: java, java-stream

I had a programming exercise to find palindrome combinations.  For example, what palindromes are in the list

```
[ "abc", "def", "zzb", "cba", "yes", "fed" ]
```

The answers would be

```
["abc", "cba"], ["cba", "abc"], ["def", "fed"], ["fed", "def"], ["abc", "def", "fed", "cba"]
```

and so on.  Maybe eight for this data set.

I note that the number of combinations to consult depends roughly on N!, meaning that a list as small as ten elements means searching over three million combos.

To conserve memory I wrote functions that took the initial list and created the permutations, but each found permutation was immediately and completely processed. At no time was the entire bloated list in memory.

I didn't use Java 8 streams because I presume that I can't add to the stream source (in this case, six elements), and that internally the system would buffer the permutations into its maximum list size which would overflow memory.

Is there a stream solution in Java for this exercise?  I know how to create the palindromes.  What I seek is how to specify a small list, permutate all of its combos, and never use more than a bit of memory to get to the end result.

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: Probably you can start with something, show your implementation pre-Java 8 stream/lambda version and then ask for suggestion if you are stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "expand" a list of objects into a bigger list with stream API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740786/is-there-a-way-to-expand-a-list-of-objects-into-a-bigger-list-with-stream-api)

Comment: What's the actual goal of the challenge - to find the total number of possible combinations? You can do that without actually calculating what the combinations are.

Comment: Why does your single list have five different answers? Or what does that answer mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this static method of `java.util.stream.Stream`:

> ```
> static <T> Stream<T>  generate(Supplier<T> s)
> ```
>
> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier.

You'll need a class that returns a new combination for every invocation of `get()`. That may be a challenge to write w/o something like Python's `yield` :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *can* stream over a list of strings and use `flatMap` to map from a single string to a (sub)-stream of all permutations, effectively streaming over all permutations of all strings, without having all strings in the memory at the same time, however, that would still imply *processing* all possible permutations. If your goal is just to test whether these permutations are in the list, you can do it much simpler by just checking grouping the strings by a canonical permutation, e.g.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "zzb", "cba", "yes", "fed");
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> {
        char[] array = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return CharBuffer.wrap(array);
    }))
    .values().stream()
    .filter(group -> group.size()>1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will only process each element of the `list` once and print

```
[abc, cba]
[def, fed]
```

which are the palindromes contained in the list.

Building permutations of the groups, like printing `[abc, cba]` *and* `[cba, abc]` is not really improving the quality of the answer, however, you can also do that without building and checking all possible palindromes…